# undefined error when build go file

Tags: go

I have a simple go file like below

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
)

var port = flag.Int("port", 23456, "port to listen.")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
}
```

It was no problem when I built it yesterday, but after upgrade to go1.2.1, I get below error.

```
d:\dev\golang>go build main.go
# flag
C:\Go\src\pkg\flag\flag.go:87: undefined: strconv.ParseBool
```

Tried to uninstall 1.2.1 and re-install 1.2, same result.

Can anybody tell me why? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

go version: go1.2.windows-amd64, go1.2.1.windows-amd64
windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Something in your go install is broken. Either there's a very old strconv missing ParseBool in your path (pre go1), or something is masking the stdlib strconv. Make sure to clean out all the old files if you reinstalled.

Comment: Show the output of `go env`.

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of Go installed some where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I found the solution.

After I renamed `C:\Go\pkg\windows_amd64` to `windows_amd64\windows_amd64_111`, system automatically recreated a `C:\Go\pkg\windows_amd64` folder for me, and then, everything goes OK.

Still don't know why...